# Why is my concatenation messing up when I pass in an array?

Tags: ruby, recursion, concatenation, permutation

I wrote a method to permute an array (I realize Ruby comes with a permutation function, but I wanted to practice algorithms). I'm encountering a really weird error and have no idea why this is happening.

Here's my code:

```rb
def permute(arr)
  permutation(arr.sort)
end

def permutation(arr, result=[])
  k = nil
  result += [arr]
  (arr.length-1).times do |i|
    if arr[i] < arr[i+1]
      k = i
    end
  end
  if k.nil?
    return result
  else
    l = -1
    arr.length.times do |i|
      if arr[k] < arr[i]
        l = i
      end
      l = nil if l == -1
    end
    arr[k], arr[l] = arr[l], arr[k]
    arr = arr[0..k] + arr[k+1..-1].reverse
    return permutation(arr, result)
  end
end
```

The method is recursive, and on each successive call I concatenate `arr` to my `result` variable with `result += [arr]` because I want the method to return a nested array, e.g. `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2]..]`

However, when I call this method it gives me a completely weird result.

```rb
permute([1,2,3])
=> [[1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Why are last three results all `[3,2,1]`? And the other arrays aren't correct either. The really strange thing is that I can fix this by changing my concatenation to `result += arr`. With this change, I get the following:

```rb
permute([1,2,3])
=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

#I know that I can get my desired nested array like so, but that's beside the point
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1].each_slice(3).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I don't get the nested arrays that I want, but the output gives me the correct permutation. Why is it working correctly now, but not which I was using `result += [arr]`? Is this a Ruby bug, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're being bit by a common ruby mistake - you're modifying the original array since the 'arr' argument to permutation() is a reference to the array

Try changing:

```
result += [arr]
```

to:

```
result += [arr.dup]
```

And then presto!

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

(Incidentally, you're still monkeying with the original 'arr' values with this solution and should probably clean that up)

Comment: Hmm.. I still don't understand why result += arr works and result += [arr] doesn't. In both instances, isn't `arr` a reference to the array, with the only difference being that one is wrapped in []?

Comment: I was recommending arr.dup.  The problem with adding the pointer to array is that you change the array later, so the one in your result is changed.

Clean it up so you aren't modifying the original array parameter (since you probably don't want that), and see if that also solves your problem.  You're almost sure to need a dup in there somewhere.

If that doesn't fully make sense, try printing out 'arr' before and after you call permutation().